# Validate Bootstrap - Timepicker start and end time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want user to select valid start and end time. For example ending time should be greater than start time. I am using **bootstrap- timepicker** gem

So far I have like this:

HTML

```
<p>   Start time:
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
              <%= f.text_field :work1, :id=> 'timepicker' ,:class => 'input-small' %>
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>

    </div>

  End time
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">

     <%= f.text_field :work2, :id=> 'timepicker1' ,:class => 'input-small' %>
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>

    </div> </p>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#timepicker, #timepicker1").timepicker(  {
                showMeridian: false

            }); 

             $("#timepicker1").change(function () {
                 var startDate = document.getElementById("timepicker").value;
                var endDate = document.getElementById("timepicker1").value;

                if ((Date.parse(endDate) <= Date.parse(startDate))) {
                 alert("End time should be greater than Start time");
                document.getElementById("timepicker1").value = "";
   } });
```

When I change Ending time, there is no errors on console.
I believe it could be because of `Date.parse`. It should be Time ? I tried to `Time.parse` but got error in console. `Time is not defined`.

Thanks!

Comment: `alert(Date.parse(endDate))` before the if //debug

Comment: @codehx I don't understand your solution. Before If I have semicol.

Comment: it is not a solution I am helping you debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joris de Wit plugin bootstrap timepicker then this is your solution [Bootstrap-timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker)

```
$('#opening').timepicker().on('hide.timepicker', function(e) {
     openingHour = e.time.hours;
     openingMinutes = e.time.minutes;
     document.getElementById('closing').value = "";    
});

$('#closing').timepicker().on('hide.timepicker', function(e) {
     closingHour =  e.time.hours;
     closingMinutes = e.time.minutes;

     if(closingHour < openingHour){
         document.getElementById('closing').value = "";
         alert("End Time should be greater than Opening Time");
     }

     if(openingHour == closingHour && openingMinutes > closingMinutes){
         document.getElementById('closing').value = "";
         alert("End Time should be greater than Opening Time");
     }
});
```

Comment: it doesnt consider the AM PM

Comment: it uses 24-hour format. where are you facing the issue?